# The Age of Jobs and Technology

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story

> Many years ago, Macintosh does not have a place in the technology field. Nokia was the beacon, the headlight of the kingdom of technology. Yet, there is a hidden force, in the far East, triggered by the extreme jealousy. The owner of what is now known as Nikoli was standing on top of the mountain, trying to make his depression fade away with the light wind that caresses his cheeks.
>
> While people are struggling for power and the leading status in technology, in the capital of Italy, people, despite having almost no access to technology, are relaxingly dancing in the Stone Hall.

Answer is a word.

### **Hints**

1

> The answer should be something that some words in the message share in common.

2

> Part of the title is a hint.

3

> What does Macintosh not have?

4

> It seems like someone is reaching the answer, step by step...

5

> This word is a type of food.

*This puzzle was partially inspired by one of [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)'s puzzles.*

Comment: Age of Jobs... should be $56$ ^^

Comment: Ok. Ok. I might be really dumb, but what's the question here?

Comment: Is the extra "h" in hint 3 deliberate?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan no, it's a typo, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @tuskiomi this is an enigmatic-puzzle. The mechanism should be found by the solver, and is not explicitly stated. The only information you have are in the puzzle.

Comment: isn't this akin to handing someone a math test with just equations and no instructions written on it?

Comment: @tuskiomi And that's the difference between a maths problem and a puzzle!

Comment:  ............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me as if TheSimpliFire figured out the answer and stated it in the comments to the OP, but that was several hours ago so I assume they're not going to make an actual answer at this point. (Maybe they were just guessing?) So let me fill in the details, or at least as many as I've been able to find; I'm missing a few.

The word we are looking for is surely

> APPLE

and

> the text we're presented with contains several references to varieties of apple.

```
Many years ago, Macintosh does not have a place in the technology field.
```

> [McIntosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McIntosh_(apple)).

```
Nokia was the beacon, the headlight of the kingdom of technology.
```

> [Beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_(apple)).

```
Yet, there is a hidden force,
```

> Just a reference to Sir Isaac Newton?

```
in the far East,
```

> There are lots of Japanese apple varieties, some named after places in Japan. The most obvious candidate seems to fit better elsewhere (see below). There don't appear to be varieties called Orient or Sunrise, though there is a Sunset. Not sure exactly what we're after here.

```
triggered by the extreme jealousy.
```

> [Envy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envy_(apple)).

```
The owner of what is now known as Nikoli
```

> The puzzle publisher Nikoli is named after a successful racehorse, hence a [Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champion_(apple)). (The *owner* of the publisher is Maki Kaji, and there doesn't seem to be an apple variety of that name; the owner of the racehorse, an Anglo-Irish nobleman, has a number of names and titles -- Guinness, Iveagh, Elveden -- but none seems to match an apple variety.)

```
was standing on top of the mountain,
```

> The mountain may be [Fuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuji_(apple)).

```
trying to make his depression fade away
```

> Not sure what's up here. There are various kinds of apple with "Delight" in the name, but that's a bit loose.

```
with the light wind that caresses his cheeks.
```

> [Breeze](https://www.sagefruit.com/our-fruit/apple-supplier/breeze-apples/).

```
While people are struggling for power
```

> Not sure what's up here. There are Empire and Liberty apples, either of which might be kinda appropriate here.

```
and the leading status in technology,
```

> Not sure what's up here. Just another reference to Apple-the-company?

```
in the capital of Italy,
```

> [Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome_apple).

```
people, despite having almost no access to technology,
```

> Presumably this is pointing at something but I haven't found it.

```
are relaxingly dancing
```

> Perhaps [Jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_(apple)). There's a Flamenco too but I don't think that's very relaxing. (Also Fiesta, Gala.)

```
in the Stone Hall.
```

> This must be referring to something too, but again I've failed to find it. There are a number of varieties named for places that probably have stone halls (e.g., Blenheim Orange) but I'm not sure any of them have stone halls that are specifically called "the Stone Hall".

Comment: i think you got most of them! stone was rot13(bcny), and i think that's it? well done!